# How to prove that $\zeta*\zeta=\zeta$?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, algebraic-groups, automorphic-forms

Let $F$ be a non-archimedean local field and $\mathcal{O}_F$ the ring of integers in $F$. Let $G_F=GL_2(F)$.

Let $\pi_i$, $i=1,\ldots,n$,be non-equivalent finite dimensional irreducible representations of $GL_2(\mathcal{O}_F)$ and $$
\zeta(g):=\sum_i \dim(\pi_i) tr(\pi_i(g^{-1})).
$$

I am trying to prove that $\zeta*\zeta=\zeta$. Here $*$ is the multiplication in the Hecke algebra associated to $G_F=GL_2(F)$. We have
$$
(\zeta*\zeta)(h) \\
= \int_{G_F} \zeta(g) \zeta(g^{-1} h ) dg \\
= \int_{G_F} (\sum_i \dim(\pi_i) tr(\pi_i(g^{-1})) ) (\sum_i \dim(\pi_i) tr(\pi_i(h^{-1} g)) )  dg \\ 
= \sum_{i,j} \int_{G_F} \dim(\pi_i) \dim(\pi_j) tr(\pi_i(g^{-1}))  tr(\pi_j(h^{-1} g))  dg.  \quad (1)
$$
But how could we show that $(1) = \zeta(h)$? Thank you very much.

Edit: this is an excise on the top of page 5 of [the notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~rhoades/FILES/Lang.pdf).

Comment: Dear LJR, I think the kind of identity you want should ultimately follow from the orthogonality relations for characters of a finite group, but there is something strange about your precise set-up: e.g. $\pi_i(g^{-1})$ is only defined for $g \in GL_2(\mathcal O_F)$, but your integral is over $G_F$.  Regards,

Comment: @MattE, thank you very much. I think that $\pi_i(g^{-1})$ is defined for $g\in G_F$. But I am not sure. In the notes, it is defined for $g \in GL_2(\mathcal{O}_F)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these computations are happening just on $GL_2(\mathcal O_F)$.  (If you like, just
extend the functions by zero from $GL_2(\mathcal O_F)$ to $GL_2(F)$.)

Then, as the exercise hints, this is just the orthogonality relations for
representations of the pro-finite group $GL_2(\mathcal O_F)$.  (Note that
since only finitely many reps. are involved, they are all actually reps.
of some finite quotient $G$ of $GL_2(\mathcal O_F)$, and so this reduces 
to orthogonality for the finite group $G$.)

Comment: thank you very much. Do we have $\int_{G_F} tr(\pi_i(g^{-1}))tr(\pi_j(h^{-1}g)) dg =0$ for $i \ne j$?

Comment: If $\int_{G_F} tr(\pi_i(g^{-1}))tr(\pi_j(h^{-1}g)) dg =0$ for $i \ne j$, then $(1) = \sum_i \int_{G_F} \dim(\pi_i)^2 tr(\pi_i(g^{-1}))tr(\pi_i(h^{-1}g) dg $.